# WooCommerce get endpoint url not returning correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, account

I'm currently trying to get link of an endpoint with this function within an WordPress AJAX call's function:

```
wc_get_endpoint_url( 'einstellungen' )
```

When I do it within a WooCommerce page, I'm getting the correct link in this format:

```
www.page.com/account/einstellungen
```

Within my AJAX function the URL is returned this way:

```
www.page.com/einstellungen
```

So it seems that the account subpage is missing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page path change depending on where you use `wc_get_endpoint_url( $endpoint )`, so in a backend function hooked in WordPress ajax `wp_ajax_{$action}` and/or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` you will always get the home url path + the endpoint slug…

Instead you have 2 ways:

1) the function [`wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $endpoint )`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_account_endpoint_url.html#165-182) that will work nicely:

```
echo wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'einstellungen' );
```

2) Or you could also use `wc_get_endpoint_url( $endpoint, '', $permalink )`, where `$permalink` *(the third argument)* will be like:

```
echo wc_get_endpoint_url( 'einstellungen', '', get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
```

> So now as you can see [`wc_get_endpoint_url()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_endpoint_url.html#76-116) function has 3 available arguments:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Get endpoint URL.
>  *
>  * Gets the URL for an endpoint, which varies depending on permalink settings.
>  *
>  * @param  string $endpoint  Endpoint slug.
>  * @param  string $value     Query param value.
>  * @param  string $permalink Permalink.
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> function wc_get_endpoint_url( $endpoint, $value = '', $permalink = '' ) {
> ```

Comment: Can you maybe check my question about the pending hook? :) I'm sure you know which hook I can use. I can't find the right solution :/.

Comment: Okay I'll do this in the afternoon because I'm at work now. This is the problem I've: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263261/woocommerce-oder-status-hook-not-triggering/56263609#56263609 I'll write you later :) Looking forward!

Comment: @Mr.Jo There is not enough context and details on your question. The "pending" status is the default status for orders before they get on the payment gateway, on order creation.

Comment: The point is that I want to call a custom function for each order when it get's created for the first time so I used the hook from the question because this is the initial status. How can I do it a better way without calling it twice?

Comment: Always @LoicTheAztec when there's a great Woo answer. My 2c is I preferred using wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) for the 3 parameter