# Woocommerce hook on custom status change wont trigger when used in trannsactional email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I am unable to get transactional email on status change. I have custom statuses and custom emails set on woo commerce plugin I programmed to my needs.

The code follows same logic as for ootb transactional emails described [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8bc310008c4786f3c7a8ecfc99b470accc77c183/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  WooCommerce Custom Statuses

*/




if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    return;
}


/**
 * Class Custom_WC_Email
 */
class WC_LR_custom_order_statuses
{

    /**
     * Custom_WC_Email constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Filtering the emails and adding our own email.
        add_filter('woocommerce_email_classes', array($this, 'lr_register_emails'), 10, 1);
        add_filter('woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', [$this, 'lr_register_statuses'], 10, 1);
        add_filter('wc_order_statuses', [$this, 'lr_custom_wc_order_statuses']);
        add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', [$this, 'lr_custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order'], 20, 1);

        foreach (['post', 'shop_order'] as $hook)
            add_filter("views_edit-$hook", [$this, 'lr_shop_order_modified_views']);


        add_action('admin_head', [$this, 'lr_change_order_processing_row_color']);
        //add_action('init', [$this, 'register_statuses']);




        // add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', [$this,'littlerug_add_custom_box'] );
        // add_action( 'save_post', [$this,'littlerug_save_postdata'], 1, 2 );


        // Absolute path to the plugin folder.
        define('CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
    }
    function lr_shop_order_modified_views($views)
    {
        // if( isset( $views['wc-completed'] ) )
        //     $views['wc-completed'] = str_replace( 'Completed', __( 'Order Received', 'woocommerce'), $views['wc-completed'] );

        if (isset($views['wc-processing']))
            $views['wc-processing'] = str_replace('Spracováva sa', 'Čakajúce na platbu', $views['wc-processing']);

        if (isset($views['wc-on-hold'])) {
            if (preg_match('/Čaká/', $views['wc-on-hold']))
                $views['wc-on-hold'] = str_replace('Čaká', 'Prijatá', $views['wc-on-hold']);
            else
                $views['wc-on-hold'] = str_replace('Čakajúce', 'Prijaté', $views['wc-on-hold']);
        }
        // if( isset( $views['wc-pending'] ) )
        //     $views['wc-pending'] = str_replace( 'Pending', __( 'Stucked', 'woocommerce'), $views['wc-pending'] );

        return $views;
    }
    function lr_custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order($actions)
    {
        unset($actions['mark_processing']);
        unset($actions['mark_pending']);
        unset($actions['mark_cancelled']);
        unset($actions['mark_completed']);

        $actions['mark_on-hold']    = 'Zmeniť stav na "Prijatá"';
        $actions['mark_order-confirmed']    = 'Zmeniť stav na "Potvrdená"';
        $actions['mark_payment-await'] = 'Zmeniť stav na "Čaká na platbu"';
        $actions['mark_payment-received']    = 'Zmeniť stav na "Platba prijatá"';
        $actions['mark_order-shipped']    = 'Zmeniť stav na "Odoslaná"';
        $actions['mark_completed']    = 'Zmeniť stav na "Vybavená"';
        $actions['mark_order-done']    = 'Zmeniť stav na "Hotová"';
        $actions['mark_cancelled'] = 'Zmeniť stav na "Zrušená"';

        return $actions;
    }
    function lr_change_order_processing_row_color()
    {

        echo sprintf(
            '
            <style type="text/css">
                .order-status.status-order-shipped {
                    background: #c8d7e1;
                    color: #2e4453;
                }
                .order-status.status-order-confirmed {
                    background: #edc77a;
                    color: #a36e03;
                }
                .order-status.status-payment-received {
                    background: #8cd98c;
                    color: #507418;
                }
                .order-status.status-order-done {
                    background: #fdfd96;
                    color: #8f8f12;
                }.order-status.status-payment-await {
                    background: #c6e1c6;
                    color: #5b841b;
                }
            </style>'
        );
    }
    function lr_custom_wc_order_statuses($order_statuses)
    {
        //change default status names add new
        unset($order_statuses['wc-processing']);
        unset($order_statuses['wc-pending']);
        unset($order_statuses['wc-completed']);
        unset($order_statuses['wc-cancelled']);
        unset($order_statuses['wc-refunded']);
        unset($order_statuses['wc-failed']);

        $order_statuses['wc-on-hold'] = _x('Prijatá', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-order-confirmed'] = _x('Potvrdená', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-payment-await'] = _x('Čaká na platbu', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-payment-received'] = _x('Platba prijatá', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-order-shipped'] = _x('Odoslaná', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-completed'] = _x('Vybavená', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-order-done'] = _x('Hotová', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-cancelled'] = _x('Zrušená', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        $order_statuses['wc-refunded'] = _x('Refundovaná', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');

        return $order_statuses;
    }
    /**
     * @param array $emails
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function lr_register_emails($emails)


    {

        $emails['WC_Customer_Cancel_Order'] = include __DIR__ . '/emails/class-wc-customer-cancel-order.php';
        $emails['WC_Customer_Payment_Received'] =  include __DIR__ . '/emails/class-wc-customer-payment-received.php';
        $emails['WC_Customer_Order_Shipped'] =  include __DIR__ . '/emails/class-wc-customer-order-shipped.php';
        $emails['WC_Customer_Order_Confirmed'] =  include __DIR__ . '/emails/class-wc-customer-order-confirmed.php';
        $emails['WC_Customer_Payment_Await'] =  include __DIR__ . '/emails/class-wc-customer-payment-await.php';
        //customer_processing_order
        // $emails['WC_Customer_Order_Placed'] = new WC_Customer_Order_Placed();
        return $emails;
    }
    public function lr_register_statuses($order_statuses)
    {
        // Status must start with "wc-"
        $order_statuses['wc-payment-await'] = array(
            'label'                     => 'Čaká na platbu', //_x( 'Back Order', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop('Čaká na platbu <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Čaká na platbu <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce') //_n_noop( 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
        );
        $order_statuses['wc-payment-received'] =  array(
            'label'                     => 'Platba prijatá', //_x( 'Back Order', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop('Platba prijatá <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Platieb prijatých <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce') //_n_noop( 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
        );
        $order_statuses['wc-order-shipped'] =  array(
            'label'                     => 'Odoslaná', //_x( 'Back Order', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop('Odoslaná <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Odoslané <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce') //_n_noop( 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
        );
        $order_statuses['wc-order-confirmed'] = array(
            'label'                     => 'Potvrdená', //_x( 'Back Order', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop('Potvrdená <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Potvrdené <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce') //_n_noop( 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
        );
        $order_statuses['wc-order-done'] = array(
            'label'                     => 'Hotová', //_x( 'Back Order', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop('Hotová <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Hotové <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce') //_n_noop( 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Back Order <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
        );

        return $order_statuses;
    }
}

new WC_LR_custom_order_statuses();
```

Same issue was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263261/woocommerce-order-status-hook-not-triggering) but I am doing it correctly with the statuses not using wc- prefix

Any advice how to debug this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I needed to add email actions. No idea why, did not see any documentation around this but this was the breaking point :)

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_email_actions', [$this, 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions'], 10, 1);

function filter_woocommerce_email_actions($actions)
{
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_confirmed';
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_payment-await';
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_payment-received';
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_shipped';
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled';
    return $actions;
}
```

After the extended email with the action hook names same as above started to trigger and email was sent successfully.