# WooCommerce hooks after order are not triggering

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a custom API call after an order made in WooCommerce is completed.

I'm having a problem where none of the hooks seem to be triggering.
Whenever i make and pay for an order everything works correctly but none of the woocommerce 'order' hooks are triggered.

So far, I've tried the following hooks:

- woocommerce_payment_complete
- woocommerce_thankyou
- woocommerce_order_status_completed
- woocommerce_order_status_changed
- woocommerce_new_order
- woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status_completed

I've tried a simple function for each, sending an email, and also logging to the debug.log.
None of these hooks are triggered when I make and pay for an order.

I'm using Oxygen Builder for my WordPress website.

Here is an example of some code using one of the hooks :

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','callback_function_2' );

function callback_function_2( $orderid ){
    
    $to_email = 'xyxyxy@gmail.com';
    $payment = "payment text - woocommerce_payment_complete";
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <test@test.com>' . '\r\n';
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject 2', $payment, $headers );

  exit;
}
```

Anyone had this problem?

Some threads that I tried :

- [WooCommerce order status hook not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263261/woocommerce-order-status-hook-not-triggering)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212400/woocommerce-hook-after-creating-order
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134463/woocommerce-order-status-completed-action-hook-not-working
- [woocommerce_order_status_completed not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315825/woocommerce-order-status-completed-not-triggered)

Comment: You need to show your code, and what you have tried.

Comment: The code that you added, doesn't reflect the External API call that you are trying to implement, using those WooCommerce hooks, so nobody can guess by magic what you are really trying to do… Try to clarify your question, if you want to get a chance to have a useful answer…

Comment: the issue is that none of the hooks are triggered.... the sample code i gave should fire off an email, but that's just a test, and is not triggered.... i'll try rephrasing slightly...

Comment: @Dog So this seems related to something else, something that is making trouble with those WooCommerce hooks… It could be a plugin or some custom code you have previously added… I can confirm that order status hooks are effectively triggered when the order status change, in a normal stable WooCommerce configuration, so for example `woocommerce_order_status_completed` is always triggered when the order status is changed to completed...

Comment: @loic yes, unfortunately it looks like something is affecting these hooks as they 'should' work... possibly the payment gateway plugin....

Comment: I have the same issue... "woocommerce_checkout_create_order" is never called... fresh install with the latest stuff

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'callback_function_2', 10, 1);

function callback_function_2($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    $to_email = 'xyxyxy@gmail.com';
    $payment = "payment text - woocommerce_payment_complete";
    $headers = 'From: Your Name <test@test.com>' . '\r\n';
    
    wp_mail($to_email, 'subject 2', $payment, $headers);
}
```